# Send array to javascript from Symfony controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, symfony4, symfony5

I need to send data array from Controller, but i don't know what is the good way. I think the controller should send the array in json.
This is my js code:

```
 $.typeahead({
        input: '[data-autocomplete="team"]',
        minLength: 1,
        order: "asc",
        offset: true,
        hint: true,
        source: {
             items: {
                 data: [here, i need to get array data from controller]
                 ajax: {
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "/teams",
                     data: {
                         myKey: $('[data-autocomplete="team"]').val()
                     }
                 }
             }
         },
    });
```

and this is my controller

```
    /**
     * @Route(name="teams", path="/teams")
     */
    public function sendTeams()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $teams = $em->getRepository(Teams::class)->findAll();
        $data = [];
        foreach($teams as $team){
           $data[] = $team->getName();
        }

        return new JsonResponse($data, 200, [], true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a JsonReponse is a proper solution.

But there is multiple way your code could be improved.

If your project is configured with the default autowiring options, you could auto wire your repository *(which by the way would have been better if called `TeamRepository` associated to a `Team` entity instead of `Teams`)*:

```
/**
 * @Route(name="teams", path="/teams")
 */
public function sendTeams(TeamsRepository $teamsRepository)
{
    $teams = $teamsRepository->findAll();
    $data = [];
    foreach($teams as $team){
       $data[] = $team->getName();
    }

    return new JsonResponse($data, 200, [], true);
}
```

You should also not set the `bool $json` parameter of `JsonResponse` since `$data` is not a json but an array that you want to be **converted into a json.** Using a JsonResponse will return a proper JsonResponse with **json headers**, the `bool $json` parameter just help converting a php variable into a json (if possible).

```
/**
 * @Route(name="teams", path="/teams")
 */
public function sendTeams(TeamsRepository $teamsRepository)
{
    $teams = $teamsRepository->findAll();
    $data = [];
    foreach($teams as $team){
       $data[] = $team->getName();
    }

    return new JsonResponse($data);
}
```

You could also simplify your foreach **(The arrow key function is php 7.4+, use a regular callable otherwise)**:

```
/**
 * @Route(name="teams", path="/teams")
 */
public function sendTeams(TeamsRepository $teamsRepository)
{
    $teams = $teamsRepository->findAll();
    $data = array_map(fn($e) => $e->getName(), $teams);

    return new JsonResponse($data);
}
```

It depends of you, but you could also use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) to not write manually the path to your `teams` route. You can check how to use it if you want.

Comment: thanks for the improvements, I am going to apply them, however, something is wrong between the controller and the javascript, as it is not working correctly... if I hardcode the array in the javascript it works fine, but through the controller, it is not working.

Comment: There should be an issue with how you receive your data in your javascript. You could try to check your url to see if you get the proper json (**url.com/teams**).

Comment: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md The documentation seems to say that you need to use `asyncResults ` with ajax Request

Comment: you were right, thank you very much for the help